# Cleveref and breqn packages don't play nice together

Tags: cross-referencing, incompatibility, cleveref, breqn

I have been using the `breqn` and `cleveref` packages independently, and I think they are both excellent packages; but recently I have tried using them together, but it appears that `cleveref` cannot identify the `dmath` environment so that all my references to equations reference the containing section. Is there a way to make these package work together?

Here's a MWE illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Content}

\begin{dmath}\label{equ:test}
a=d+c
\end{dmath}
\cref{equ:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a "Minimal Working Example" (MWE) of your code.

Comment: Please, as Mico suggested, post a MWE of your code. I did it for you in my edit (for the sake of the quality of the question) but you are free to roll back or add an MWE of your own if you want to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative answer, which allows you to use `\label` as normal:

The problem is caused by the fact that `cleveref` relies on redefining `\refstepcounter`, while `breqn` doesn't actually use this to advance the `equation` counter. Fortunately the `cleveref` code for dealing with footnotes, which don't use `\refstepcounter` either, provides a basis for dealing with `dmath`s as another special case by adding some code to `\eq@setnumber`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\cref@old@eq@setnumber\eq@setnumber
\def\eq@setnumber{%
\cref@old@eq@setnumber%
\cref@constructprefix{equation}{\cref@result}%
\protected@xdef\cref@currentlabel{%
[equation][\arabic{equation}][\cref@result]\p@equation\theequation}}
\makeatother
```

Including this code in the preamble yields the correct result for the MWE.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for the quick response Ant!

Answer (score 3):

I used to use [Ant's makeatletter method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28607/15), but with the packages contained in the Feb 2014 MikTex 2.9 installation:

```
Package: cleveref 2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package: breqn 2012/05/10 v0.98b Breaking equations
```

this starts causing:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]
```

errors.

It also seems like dmath and cleverref now play together well by default, so upgrading the latex packages now appears to be a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal, but a workaround is to add an optional argument `equation` to each label:

```
\label[equation]{equ:test}
```

Comment: it may not be ideal, but it's probably the best you are going to achieve.  (the author of cleveref could in principle read all packages and identify labellable envs that they introduce so as to program round them, but it's not likely to happen, is it?)

Comment: Fortunately not every environment needs to be dealt with individually. If the environment number is incremented with `\refstepcounter` then `cleveref` should work automagically. If not, you can insert the patch of `\refstepcounter` into whatever command is used instead by hand - see my other answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The dmath displays as equation, but the counters aren't right.  Your other answer appears to be required.

Comment: This doesn't work, the argument to `\label` becomes just the opening bracket `[`.  I guess options to `\label` require a special package?