# How to plot data from a CSV file and label axis using tikz and csvsimple?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use this code

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to plot my data

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
year,count
2016,998
2015,1000
2014,900
2013,837
2012,826
2011,784
2010,801
2009,731
2008,703
2007,632
2006,629
2005,516
2004,512
2003,476
2002,444
2001,497
2000,478
1999,400
1998,393
1997,399
1996,387
\end{filecontents*}
```

First issue conserns the number on the x and y axis is comma separated value, how to fix it,
second issue is about axis labeling, how to put the lables?
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. For the first, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31276 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28607. For the second, `\begin{axis}[xlabel=foo,ylabel=bar]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example. Find some knowledge in the [manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) with the corresponding [gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) or around [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346936/140011).

This line `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}` lets you adjust the separator (sep option).

The label can be set here `\begin{axis}[ xlabel=Count, ylabel=Year]`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={\,}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=Count, ylabel=Year]


\addplot[color=blue,mark=*] table[x=year, y=count, col sep=comma]{data.csv};

 \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this needs to go before the picture line, but for a shorter example I stuck this here:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
year,count
2016,998
2015,1000
2014,900
2013,837
2012,826
2011,784
2010,801
2009,731
2008,703
2007,632
2006,629
2005,516
2004,512
2003,476
2002,444
2001,497
2000,478
1999,400
1998,393
1997,399
1996,387
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: In general, don't use the `minimal` class, `article` is a better choice: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided (And `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, so you don't need to explicitly load the latter, strictly speaking.)